# Delphi мессенджер. Какие компоненты использовать?

Tags: delphi, gui, delphi-7, ui

Пишу мессенджер на Delphi7. Прошу помощи: как сделать пользовательский интерфейс примерно как в телеграме, ватсаппе и т.д.

1. Какие компоненты использовать чтобы при нажатии на i-ую вкладку слева изменялось окно чата справа? (я не придумал ничего лучше PageControl)
2. Как(на каком компоненте) отображать исходящие и входящие сообщения и скроллить их? (у меня вообще нет идей как это делать)
3. Как сделать облако сообщения? Я имею ввиду, чтобы сообщения отображались не сплошным текстом, а были отделены как-то (я не придумал ничего лучше как много tMemo'ов, т.е. для каждого сообщения свой tMemo)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знающие люди, подскажите, подкиньте идей, пожалуйста
Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Я бы делал на двух tlistview tedit и tbutton. Но посмотрите на tvirtualstringtree и подобные сторонние компоненты

Comment: TVS тут явно не вариант на таком уровне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в delphi есть все для этого кроме стандартного scrollbox который глючит когда тысячи  сообщений там будет.
поэтому сам писал свой скрол бокс который делился на 3 листа 1 что невидно снизу 2 что видно 3 что не видно сверху плюс динамическая подгрузка сообщений при скроле
конечно в delphi есть все но все же вам придется писать свои компоненты на основе стандартных а пытаться найти что то готовое ничему не научит и не факт что на 100% они подойдут под вашу задумку.

1. Какие компоненты использовать чтобы при нажатии на i-ую вкладку слева изменялось окно чата справа?
   Я делал с помощью TPanel все и ее разновидностей
   PageControl стандартный не подойдет вообще.
   вам нужен полный доступ к окнам что бы на панель навесить другие панели а PageControl вкладка это не окно а просто отрисовка вкладки.
   поэтому создаете вначале скролл бокс который не будет глючить он у вас будет кастомным от него унаследуясь создаете
   отдельные скролбоксы для панели контактов
   и панели диалогов
   создаете все динамически и при создании на каждую ячейку скролбокса т.е контакта вешаете onlick  в событии ContactClick(Sender:TObject)
   вы получите объект контакта а дальше загрузите для него историю диалога в скролбокс для диалога.
2. Как(на каком компоненте) отображать исходящие и входящие сообщения и скролить их?
   Только свой скрол бокс с нуля писать надо. другие варики плохо будут работать(я протестил все что можно, но только свой норм)
3. Как сделать облако сообщения? Я имею ввиду, чтобы сообщения отображались не сплошным текстом, а были отделены как-то
   допустим вы написали свой ScrollBox с нуля. TBoxHistory

каждый элемент TBoxHistory для истории диалога должен содержать какие то панели  (TBoxHistoryItem) в свою очередь (TBoxHistoryItem) должна содержать
несколько сообщений (TBoxHistoryItemContent) в ней может быть или текст или картинки или видео или все вместе (это то что видит юзер)

юзер не видит (TBoxHistoryItem) а она нужна для оптимизации прокрутки, что бы комп меньше напрягался что бы при скроле выводить на экран сообщения блоками а не по одному

т.е схема такая [image: Картинка]

что использовать для отображения текста (тут у меня тоже есть вопросы), но я использовал TLabel (это менее затратно по ресурсам)
но если юзер хочет выделить или скопировать то при клике TLabel  заменятся на TMemo цветной когда операция завершена Tlabel обратно вернется на место.

Сейчас копался в давно скаченных компонентах искал функцию нашел готовое решение для чата правда с некоторыми недостатками но это лучше чем с кучей окно возится оч похоже на телегу парень(наверно) старался скопировать. Для всяких мелких чатов пойдет хотя я попровал в него запихнуть 10000 сообщений вроде работает. но если фотки и другая графика будет нужно будет оптимизировать. Все выполнено в одном компоненте и рисуется не отдельно а разом в Paint
https://github.com/HemulGM/Components
модуль HGM.Controls.Chat.pas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем же эти выкрутасы с компонентами, не предназначенными для подобных задач?! Тем более компонент `TScrollBox`, который при верт. прокрутке изменяет позицию ВСЕХ дочерних компонентов? Проще свой `TMessageBoardViewer` написать, который будет только и заниматься тем, что отображать информацию (в даном случае - сообщения).

Comment: @Josef Švejk
выкрутасы для оптимизации чем меньше Размер массива TWinControl.ControlCount тем быстрее все работает, иначе  на слабых компах юзер полчаса будет ждать если захочет на пиксель изменить размер проги. а сами сообщения должны изменятся при изменение размеров скрола. как по ширине так и по высоте. По-мойму ваш коммент о тоже самом что и мой ответ. Или вы говорите о рисунке сообщений на TPanel?

Comment: да, я имел в виду, что и сообщения и контент этих сообщений следует исключительно рисовать по требованию (в момент прокрутки, например), не прибегая к "оконным" компонентам. Сначала я прочел Ваш ответ и решил, что Вы `TPanel` (в качестве сообщений) отображаете на компоненте `TScrollBox`. Теперь понимаю, что я ошибался. Правильно ли я понимаю: Ваш `TBoxHistoryItem` это невизуальный класс, который только хранит информацию, а отображением информации занимается "оконный" компонент `TBoxHistory`?

Comment: В любом случае, Ваш вариант вполне здравый. Плюсанул ответ. Кстати, где можно потестить (хотя бы черновой, без доступа к Интернету) вариант Вашего чата/компонента?

Comment: @Josef Švejk
https://github.com/dvb01/exe там вот такое когда писал скрол там тестил https://prnt.sc/26vx5h2 если чат нужен в телегу напиши скину клиент и сервер  localike

Comment: @Josef Švejk
 все что на схеме рисовал это визуальные компоненты от TWinControl . тот чат я для себя как тест делал. типа смогу не смогу и довольно давно эт было. сейчас бы я иначе делал. в том скрол боксе количество контролов = кол-ву сообщений.  конечно все в базе не визуальной хранится. просто те контролы что не видны их parent =nil и они в другом листе.  и даж если котролов ...

Comment: @Josef Švejk  ... 50 000 (такое тестил) ничего не лагало. недавно писал другой скрол бокс (к этому чату не имеет отношения) там я уже не создавал тысячи контролов. а только необходимое для клиентской области. таким образом решил проблему долгой загрузки тысяч элементов.  т.е есть визуальный котрол  V у него есть невизуальный NV - это элемент скрол бокса и у NV есть BAZA (база данных что там выводить на экран). Ну и получается Items может быть очень много а в скрол боксе только 20 их а бар сам скрол считается по NV